How does rounding works in float multiplication?
The exact value of float 0.7f is 0.69999...
so I thought the result of 0.7f * 100f would be something below 70, like 69.99999...
But the result is exact 70.
Does float multiplication involve such rounding?
If so, is such post processing applicable in fixed-point as well?
I found in some fixed-point libraries, FP(100) * FP(0.7) is 69.99999.
When casting this to int, they ruthlessly truncate and I get 69. Which is undesirable since FP can express exact 70.

69.99999... is not exactly representable as float either, so it needs to get rounded. For some decimal fractions 100 * 0.xy happens to be rounded to exactly xy -- but you can't rely on that. If you want to represent 0.7 exactly, don't use binary floating points.

This question is similar to: Is floating-point math broken?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@chtz I believe this is a different question. The linked question is about float representation itself, while mine is about how rounding occurs in multiplication.

Finite-precision binary floating point cannot represent every real (or every decimal) number exactly, but it should always represent the closest possible number.
Finite-precision floating point arithmetic cannot compute every possible result, either, but it is required (at least in ordinary cases) to compute a properly-rounded result.
The exact (closest representable) single-precision float corresponding to 0.7 is 0b0.101100110011001100110011, which when converted back to decimal is 0.699999988079071044921875.  Notice that this number has 24 significant bits, which is part of the definition of IEEE-754 single precision.
Multiplying this number by 100 would give us 0b1000101.1111111111111111111011.  But that number has 29 significant bits, so it won't fit in the 24 bits of significance available in single precision.  So we have to round it off.  Now, the 25th bit is 1, so we round up, and just about all the bits to the left of that 25th bit are 1, so it rounds all the way up to 0b1000110.00000000000000000, or exactly 70.0.
Note that, although single precision floating-point has 24 bits of significance, calculations involving single precision floating point must be carried out using, temporarily, more than 24 bits of precision, so that a few bits beyond the 24th can be accurately computed, so that the result can be correctly rounded, as required.
And this is a nice example of how IEEE-754's rules about properly-rounded results work, and work well.  It's easy to get the (mistaken) impression that floating-point values are always at least a little bit off, if not downright broken.  But, in fact, IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic is usually quite precise, and tries hard to keep errors from compounding — which means that, not infrequently, the errors can cancel each other out, yielding exact results after all.  That's basically what happens here.
Or, in other words, the rule is not that floating-point calculations are always imprecise.  The real rule is that floating-point calculations are sometimes imprecise — but they're also, sometimes, perfectly precise.
(In fact, an even better rule is that floating-point calculations are often imprecise as compared to an expected, but decimal, result.  If you take two binary floating-point numbers and do an operation on them, you just about always get a result that's really precise — in binary.  My point is that most of the apparent inaccuracies occur only when you compare the binary result to one which you computed, some other way, in decimal.)

If the above explanation doesn't work for you, here's another way of looking at it.  As we know, floating point representations  can't represent every number.  Indeed, one of the numbers they can't represent in binary is 0.7, and the closest representable number in single precision is a binary number that's equal to 0.699999988079071044921875.
Now, what if we take that number 0.699999988079071044921875 and multiply it by 100?  The exact result should be 69.9999988079071044921875.  But this is another number that can't be represented exactly.  If you take this nonrepresentable number 69.9999988079071044921875, and ask what the nearest number that can be represented exactly in single precision would be, that number is... 70.0!  In single precision, the next representable number less than that is 69.99999237060546875, which is farther away (in this case more than 5 times farther away) than 70.0 is.

You also asked about fixed-point libraries.  There, the answer would obviously depend on the implementation, but more importantly, on the base.  A binary fixed-point library can't represent 0.7 exactly, either.  But a decimal fixed-point library obviously could.
An "8.8" binary fixed-point representation of 0.7 would, I think, be 0000000010110011 (base 2), or 00b3 (base 16) or 179 (base 10), which converted back to a fraction is 0.69921875.  Multiplying that by 100 gives 100010111101100 / 45ec / 17900, which converts back to 69.921875.  So under those assumptions, I don't see a way to do better (that is, a way to get 70.0).
But if a decimal fixed-point library gave you 69 after multiplying, I'd say it's quite badly implemented.  A 16-bit fixed-point decimal representation of 0.7 with a scale factor of 100 would be 70, which  when multiplied by 100 gives 7000, which when divided by the scale factor again obviously gives 70.0 exactly.

The obvious question for me is why does the rounding propagate through all 24 bits, and not simply stop like "0b110.11111111111111111110".  But I guess the answer to that is in the IEE-754 rules

@PeterM I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean: that's not rounding. If you compute an intermediate result of 0b110.1111111111111111111111, with 25 bits, and if you round it off to 24 bits, the rounding must propagate up through all the bits, giving 0b111.000000000000000000000. (Otherwise it'd just be truncation.) [Also I changed the numbers in the answer after you commented, because the OP had asked about multiplying by 100, not 10.]

"the rounding must propagate"  That's the crux of my question.  I can say "round a decimal number to x significant digits", and the rounding will be implied to stop at x.  If I instead say "round a binary number to 24 bits", why does that imply (in this case) that the rounding propagates through all the bits?  I don't know if this is semantics of the verb "to round" for decimal vs binary, or if the IEE-754 rules require it.

@PeterM If someone gives me the number 6.9999999999, and asks me to round it to 5 places past the decimal, I'm going to say my answer is 7.00000.  In cases like this, the carry implied by the rounding can propagate through all of the digits/bits, it doesn't "stop".  This is true in both decimal and binary.  (This is also why 0.999… is equal to 1.

@Peter: No, it's the same in decimal. Take 7.9999947 and round it to four significant digits. You get 8.000. No other answer makes sense. The carries must propagate.

@SteveSummit  I see the error in my thinking now.  I was assuming in my head that the decimal number did not consist of decimal 9's, but the binary effectively does.  As such, I was comparing apples to oranges.

Thanks for the detailed answer. The 25th-bit rounding was an aha moment for me. I'm still a little confused about fixed-point multiplication. Can I say that fixed-point multiplication cannot be done in higher precision like float? (because it is fixed)

@yahoic I'm puzzled by the contrast with fixed-point arithmetic also; I can't explain why there doesn't seem to be a possibility of the "errors canceling each other out", as I put it.  It may be bad luck (that is, there might be other fixed-point problems where the rounding could help), or it may be that floating point has an inherent advantage here, perhaps that (being floating) it keeps more precision around for smaller numbers like 0.7.

If you multiply a fixed point number by an integer (and don't change the precision of the result), there will never be rounding. Simple decimal example with 3+3 digits: 1/6 --> 0.167 and 0.167 * 6.000 = 1.002. You cannot say that fixed-point is "less precise" than floating point. E.g. if you know that you only work with numbers in the (-2, +2) interval, and have 32bits for storage you could use 2+30 binary digits, which gives you an absolute precision of 2^-30, which is better than the (relative) precision of float32.

@yahoic I think the explanation is that in fixed point, there's no possibility of an intermediate result with excess precision, and therefore never an opportunity to round.  In fixed point, if you have an N-bit result and you multiply it by an integer, you'll either get another N-bit result, or an overflow.  In floating point, on the other hand, in general, if you multiply a number with N bits of precision by another number with N bits of precision, you get an intermediate result with 2N bits of precision, so you virtually always need to round.

Another way of looking at this is that in fixed point, all numbers have (by definition) the same absolute precision.  In floating point, on the other hand, when you make a number bigger (say, by multiplying it by a number greater than 1), the absolute precision goes down, so there's likely to be rounding involved.

In single-precision binary floating point, numbers in the range of 0.7 have a precision of ±6×10⁻⁸, while numbers in the range of 70 have a precision of ±7.6×10⁻⁶.  (Those numbers are FLT_EPSILON / 2 and FLT_EPSILON * 64, respectively.)
